# replace values throughout a tibble

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

In base R I can use the following code to remove/replace values throughout a dataframe (e.g., all NAs or values greater than 0.99).

```
df[df > 0.99] <- NA
df[is.na(df)] <- 0L
```

Is there a way to perform the equivalent operation using dplyr in the tidyverse?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use `mutate_all` with `replace`:

```
df = data.frame(x = c(1.2, 0.4, NA, 0.6), y = c(NA, 0.3, 0.992, 0.5))
df %>% mutate_all(~ replace(., . > 0.99 | is.na(.), 0))
#    x   y
#1 0.0 0.0
#2 0.4 0.3
#3 0.0 0.0
#4 0.6 0.5
```

Or use `funs`:

```
df %>% mutate_all(funs(replace(., . > 0.99 | is.na(.), 0)))
```

If you just need to integrate this as part of the pipe, `replace` method should work:

```
df %>% replace(. > 0.99 | is.na(.), 0)
```